# Does Desktop Table Tennis have any motion controls at all?

Tags: nintendo-switch, desktop-table-tennis

According to the [store page](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/desktop-table-tennis-switch/), the game claims to have motion controls and I love motion controls a lot, along with ping pong. I spent $8, and go to the exact point in the game where motion controls are supposed to be an option and nothing happens. I see nothing posted about this and I've searched everywhere.  Everything I've looked up and found online claims it has motion controls for sure. Even the trailer video for the game on the Switch did.

I've calibrated motion controls in the settings and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I've gone to the exact point where it said it had it, and I know it has it, or at least I hope it does. I contacted their support but haven't received a response yet so I really need help.

Did they just remove it or are motion controls enabled somewhere and I'm missing something?

Comment: What's the name of the game?

Comment: @Nolonar It's Desktop Table Tennis Switch edition, as referenced in the first title, in case you didn't catch it -- as a new user, they probably can't create their own tags and chose something more appropriate.

Comment: I had played a demo version, there is no any motion control setting in it. That's the reason I didn't purchase ...